# Packaging tor in a go project

Tags: go, package, tor

I was researching ways of doing various things over Tor (in go), and the only way so far that I've seen is by connecting to `127.0.0.1:9050` as a SOCKS5 proxy and talking over that.

However, in a program that end-users would receive, this would require them setting up tor on their own.

Is there some way of packaging it with the project so that when run, it automatically sets up tor - temporarily - on its own?

Comment: Easy on Windows, harder on Linux due to different distros, architectures and dependencies on openssl and the like.  Aside from that, yes it's easy to have your program launch it's own Tor daemon (preferably on a port other than 9050 or 9150) and use it.  This is what the Tor Browser Bundle does.  For Linux you might just be able to rip the Tor binaries right out of the bundle and distribute those.

Comment: @drew010 Are there any resources or guides that I should know about?

Comment: None I am aware of personally for this type of specific goal.  The documentation on how to launch the Tor daemon and what configuration options you'll want to include in your configuration is most helpful.  There's probably a lot that can be learned from the Tor Browser Bundle because you can consider Tor Browser to be the project that re-packages Tor just like you want to do.  When you launch Tor Browser, it runs its own Tor daemon and configures the browser to use the SOCKS proxy.

Comment: I have written a lib that sets up Tor and lets you link it statically: https://github.com/cretz/bine

Answer (score 1):

On Linux I recommend you specify Tor as a dependency when distributing your package. An example of this can be seen with Arch Linux's `pkgbuild` [dependencies](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PKGBUILD#Dependencies).

If people want manually check out your code and build on it, you will just have to tell them to install Tor. (Via a README, and a hard error upon execution of your program, where Tor is not installed.)

Comment: Yeah I've considered this but I'd really like some way of just launching a tor daemon automatically